# List the longest multiple directory prefixes

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I have a backup script utilizing rsync to synchronize a source and destination folder. Well that is pretty straight forward and doesn't need a 180 line bash script. The problem is that I want all modified/deleted files and directories in the source to be copied from the destination to a safe location before rsync synchronizes the directories.

I use the rsync --delete argument because, well I want the folders synchronized, just that I also want a backup of the deleted and modified files and folders. rsync lists all deleted files and folders even if the files are included in the deleted folder. The output of rsync looks like this:

```
sending incremental file list
.d..t......|Original/Artist/
*deleting  |Original/Artist/nymapp/skitfil.mp3
*deleting  |Original/Artist/nymapp/
sent 416.81K bytes  received 732 bytes  25.30K bytes/sec
total size is 89.97G  speedup is 215480.91 (DRY RUN)
```

Here both the deleted file and the deleted folder are listed. If you would simply copy everything to the right of the "|"-symbol, that starts with "*deleting" you would end up with copying files in deleted folders when you have already copied the folder and its content. Or the other way around depending on which entry is listed first in the rsync output. In case of copying a file to a folder that doesn't exist, cp will just exit with error code that the destination folder doesn't exist. So the best thing is to copy all deleted folders first and then check if the deleted files are already included in the deleted folders.

Basically I want a list of all the "parent" folders of the following example list of files and folders:

```
*deleting  |/Original/Artist/HDLC/fake.mp3
*deleting  |/Original/Various/blabla.mp3
*deleting  |/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/duh.mp3
*deleting  |/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/
*deleting  |/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/dir1/dir2/dir1/
*deleting  |/Non\ Original/hey.mp3
*deleting  |/Non\ Original/Electronic/bla.mp3
*deleting  |/Non\ Original/Electronic/dir2/
*deleting  |/Non\ Original/Synth/meh.mp3
*deleting  |/differentparent/nofile.mp3
```

The output should be:

```
/Original/Artist/HDLC/
/Original/Various/
/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/
/Non\ Original/
/Non\ Original/Electronic/
/Non\ Original/Synth/
/differentparent/
```

The reason that it is not enough to just copy the deleted folders and skip the files-part is that also deleted and modified files that reside in folders that weren't deleted should be copied to the safe location and you do not want to copy an entire folder just because one file in it was deleted.

As you see this is more complex than meets the eye at a first glance. Is there a friendly soul out there that either can present me a set of commands that would find these "parent" directories or possibly another solution to the problem.

Comment: Question is a bit confusing to me. If you're just trying to go from the list of files and folders to the output, then could explain a bit more about what the rules are. e.g. it's not clear why `/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/dir1/dir2/` shouldn't be in output?

Comment: That's because rsync has found that the entire folder **/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/** has been deleted and thus is the sub-folder **dir1/dir2/dir1/** included and already copied when cp copied the content of /Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey to the safe location. As you see in the rsync output only two folders were deleted, along with its content, be it files or folders or with no content:

`*deleting  |/Original/Artist/Dir_en_grey/`
`*deleting  |/Non\ Original/Electronic/dir2/`

Comment: No proposals..? Anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the built-in functions --backup and --backup-dir= in rsync. --backup does just what it is called and used together with --backup-dir which moves the backed up files to a safe location the problem was solved.